# Not able to fetch data based on another data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

There are 2 tables table_one and table_two, in this the id of table_one becomes the table_one_id in table_two.

View of table_one

```
id   Title
1    name1
2    name2
```

View of table_two

```
id   table_one_id   Location    Title
1      1             loc1       name1
2      1             loc2       name1
3      2             loc3       name2
```

Controller

```
$data['client_data'] = $this->admin_model->get_client_detail($id);
```

Model

```
public function get_client_detail($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get('table_two');

        return $query->result();
    }
```

I wish to change the values of table_one based on the id of table_two, for this i wish to perform the following steps

> 1) Pass the id of table_two inside variable $id.
>
> 2) Using $id fetch the value of table_one_id from table_two.
>
> 3) Compare the value of table_one_id with the id of table_one.
>
> 4) Fetch and update the values of table_one based on the id of table_one and update the same values in table_two
>   e.g if i change the value of name 2 then it should also get changed in table_two

Can anyone please how it can be done

Comment: `return $query->result();` ? or `$query = $this->db->get('table_two')->result(); return $query;` ?

Comment: @Hendra Nucleo sorry i didnt understood

Comment: This line `return $query->row()` no  `row()` even exist.

Comment: @Hendra Nucleo yes but i am still not getting the result, i am not able to make the queries properly

Comment: `$quickhireid` should be `$id` no?

Comment: @HendraNucleo yes corrected it

Comment: @Hendra Nucleo how can i get the table_one_id   from result?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i assuming the `$id` is have a value. So in your model you should writing **Active Record** query like this:

```
public_function_get_client_data($id)
{
    $returnedData = $this->db->where('table_one_id', $id)
                    ->get('table_two')
                    ->result();
    return $returnedData;
}
```

**Hint:**

1. You write the query wrong, you using `return $query->row();` it
   should be `$query->result();` in this case.
2. If the `where` condition based on table_two `id` then field table_one_id on table_two is useless.
3. `$this->db->where('id',$quickhireid);` where the `$quickhireid` variable coming from? what's going on here?

Try my code, and do `var_dump()` and check the result. If any error persist, tell it here or if it give the expected result don't be hesitated to accept this as an answer.